# How to speed up code with loop in R

Tags: r, loops

Problem:
I have two data frames.
DF with payment log:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   53682 obs. of  7 variables:


str(moneyDB)
 $ user_id : num  59017170 57859746 58507536 59017667 59017795 ...
 $ reg_date: Date, format: "2016-08-06" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-19" ...
 $ date    : Date, format: "2016-08-06" "2016-07-01" "2016-07-19" ...
 $ money   : num  0.293 0.05 0.03 0.03 7 ...
 $ type    : chr  "1" "2" "2" "1" ...
 $ quality : chr  "VG" "no_quality" "no_quality" "VG" ...
 $ geo     : chr  "Canada" "NO GEO" "NO GEO" "Canada" ...
```

Here is its structure. Its just a log of all transactions.

Also i have second data frame:

```
str(grPaysDB)

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   335591 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ reg_date      : Date, format: "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" ...
 $ date          : Date, format: "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" ...
 $ type          : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ quality       : chr  "VG" "VG" "VG" "VG" ...
 $ geo           : chr  "Australia" "Canada" "Finland" "Canada" ...
 $ uniqPayers    : num  0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 3 ...
```

Its Grouped data from first data frame + zero transactions. For example, there is a lot of rows in second data frame with zero payers. Thats why second data frame is greater then first.

I need to add column **weeklyPayers** to the second data frames. Weekly payers is sum unique payers for the last 7 days. I tried do it via loop, but it wooks too long. Is there any another vectorized ideas, how to realise this?

```
weeklyPayers <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(grPaysDB)) {
   temp <- moneyDB %>%
      filter(
         geo == grPaysDB$geo[i],
         reg_date == grPaysDB$reg_date[i],
         quality == grPaysDB$quality[i],
         type == grPaysDB$type[i],
         between(date, grPaysDB$date[i] - 6, grPaysDB$date[i])
      )

   weeklyPayers <- c(weeklyPayers, length(unique(temp$user_id)))
}
grPaysDB <- cbind(grPaysDB, weeklyPayers)
```

In this loop for each row in second data frame i find rows in first data frame with right geo,type, quality and reg_date and range of dates. And then I can calculate number of unique payers.

Comment: It's best to either use a built-in data set for the example or to share your data via `dput`

Answer (score 0):

I would try making a join on your datasets using `merge` on multiple columns (`c('geo', 'reg_date', 'quality', 'type'`) and filter the result based on the dates. After that, aggregate using `summarise`.

But I am not completely sure why you want to add the weeklypayers to every transaction. Isn't it more informative or easier to aggregate your data on week number (with `dplyr`). Like so:

```
moneyDB %>% mutate(week = date- as.POSIXlt(date)$wday) %>%
  group_by(geo, reg_date, quality, type, week) %>%
  summarise(weeklyPayers = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but I think this should be fairly simple, using filter and summarise in dplyr. However, as @Hack-R mentioned, it would be helpful to have your dataset. But it would look something like:

```
library(dplyr)
weeklyPayers <- grPaysDB %>%
   filter(date > ADD DATE IN QUESTION) %>%
   summarise(sumWeeklyPayers = sum(uniqPayers))
```

Then again, I may well have misunderstood. If your question involves summing for each week, then you may want to investigate daily2weekly in the timeSeries package and then using group_by for the weekly variable that transpires.